# Determining probability involving normal random variables and given covariance

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Say X and Y are normally distributed random variables, i.e., X,Y ~ N(0,1). For some fixed t and c I know that Pr[X≥t]=c and Pr[Y≥t]=c. Moreover, I also know that X and Y have covariance 0.999.

How can I deduce what Pr[X≥t and Y≥t] roughly is?

Bonus question: what are good references to learn more on related topics for normally distributed random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [bivariate normal distribution](http://www.athenasc.com/Bivariate-Normal.pdf). Here is a [paper](http://www.stuart.iit.edu/shared/shared_stuartfaculty/TablesfortheStandardBivariateNormalDistributionwithMontiraJantaravareerat.pdf) estimating the cdf of the bivariate normal distribution since no known analytic form is known. [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387970622) is a good book explaining multivariate normal distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help PEV.